# A lap time leader board

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm very new to coding and have searched everywhere but havent been able to figure this one out.

Im trying to create a Lap Time Leader Board for various tracks in a video game guide. The user needs to be able to Click on the track name and then inside of the new layout "Create" a new time...that needs to allow him to imput the Car and the time it did on this track, then it needs to either sort itself or be manually sortable so that the times are in order from fastest to slowest. While i can build the layout easily i get stumped there.

1. How can i make it so that when the user clicks "Create New Time" the code gives him the spaces for time and car model.
2. How can i make sure it saves the correct info with SharedPreferences since each time will need to be saved differently (i think this has to do with the name and then ++ but i could be wrong)
3. How can i make it sort itself or be sortable for the user.
4. Can someone show me some sample code that does this? I dont know much of anything about SQL and would prefer not to use it if i can avoid it.

Im sorry this is such a noob set of questions but this after trying the notepad tutorial on AD and numerous video and book tutorials i havent found what i need to make this a reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a the Dialog class to create a pop up dialog to allow the user to input the information you are looking for. Sorry that you wish to not use SQL
Shared Preferences isn't such a good idea because you will have to do a lot more work to code your desired affect. A datatbase with simple Relations(tables) will suit your needs as opposed to Shared Preferences where you'd have to get creative to have the same data structure. Such as an ArrayList of BasicNameValuePairs, that could be a head ache. Database is the way to go, you can do everything you need if it's properly set up.

Sorting is quite easy in Java as you could always use the Collections class and implement the Comparable interface to compare your lap times to each other and sort them by total time. For a display such as that you would want to look into a TableLayout in Android XML. Don't worry so much about that, the Eclipse IDE will let you easily create and populate it. This would involve loading your laptimes from your database into a List and sorting them by time. It's a bit tricky but easy once you understand the Comparable interface and Collections if you need it. 
If you need more insight post a comment, just wanted to share some ideas on how I would approach it.

Comment: Hey thanks Ryan, Sorry for the delay but i was one of the people who had to Evac thanks to the Waldo Canyon Fire here in Colorado Springs. So it looks like i'll be looking into learning SQL and more about the Collections Class and Comparable Interface. Most of all that is well over my head at the moment. It gives me a direction though so thankyou again.

Comment: I've had experience with Java and Android but am by no means an expert. If you have any more questions don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Thanks so much. Going to do as much research today as i possibly can and then hopefully consolidate whatever I cant seem to get tomorrow or Wednesday.

Comment: Ok, so after a week of work, i can understand how to get SQLite going but only really with one table and even then, its not in the positions i want it to be in. I followed this tutorial http://goo.gl/uWaMa but if you notice there, after creating the table with name and results the actual output isnt under those TextViews, so im stuck there for now. What does one need to do to populate the correlating results under the specified space of the layout?

Comment: I suggest making a new question with some code. Others will be more informative on that question than I.